# Amazon AWS Loadbalanced High-Availability Apache Cluster

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

For my WordPress application I need to setup load balanced High-Availability Apache HTTP Server Cluster. I can't find a docs describing AWS approach for Apache Cluster.

Is it possible with Amazon ELB + EC2 instances ?

Comment: I would suggest looking into Elastic Beanstalk which will handle much of this for you.

Comment: Thanks, also I have found a pretty good article about WP and Elastic  AWS Beanstalk https://bigbitecreative.com/scalable-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical example in all the documentation for ELB is a cluster of web servers.  For instance see

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-getting-started.html

The part that they do not cover is maintaining a cluster of alike apache servers that are sending the same data.  One popular approach to this is to build a custom AMI containing all the documents to be served and with all the software packages pre installed.

If you specifically want to do a wordpress elb cluster then googling "ELB wordpress" comes up with lots of hits.  However, the general guide to how it works is found in the official aws documentation such as the above